# To find partial string match in map

Tags: c++

I have a map  test and its initialize to below

```
test["auto  works"] = 1;
test["before word"] = 2;
test["before list"] = 3;
test["before pattern"] = 4;
test["before me"] = 5;
test["before hen"]  = 6;
test["has float"] = 7;
```

And i have a string search which is initialized to "before me grep lot".

Now i want to find the search string in test map. Ideally i want look a better match for search string "before me grep lot" in test map.

The output should be 5.

please help me out.

Comment: Why is `5` the "better match"?

Comment: Do you want to return *all* the keys that begin with the search string?

Answer (score 1):

Use `test.lower_bound(search)` ([documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound)).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> test;

    test["auto  works"]    = 1;
    test["before word"]    = 2;
    test["before list"]    = 3;
    test["before pattern"] = 4;
    test["before me"]      = 5;
    test["before hen"]     = 6;
    test["has float"]      = 7;

    std::string s( "before me grep lot" );
    auto it = test.lower_bound( s );

    size_t prev = 0, next = 0;

    if ( it != test.begin() )
    {        
        auto pos = std::mismatch( s.begin(), s.end(),
                                  std::prev( it )->first.begin(), std::prev( it )->first.end() );
        prev = std::distance( s.begin(), pos.first );
    }       
    if ( it != test.end() )
    {
        auto pos = std::mismatch( s.begin(), s.end(),
                                  it->first.begin(), it->first.end() );
        prev = std::distance( s.begin(), pos.first );
    }       

    std::string target = prev < next ? it->first : std::prev( it )->first;

    std::cout << "The closest item is test[\"" << target << "\"] = " << test[target] << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
The closest item is test["before me"] = 5
```

If your compiler standard library does not support algorithm std::mismatch with four parameters then the if statements can look like

```
if ( it != test.begin() )
{
    std::cout << std::prev( it )->first << std::endl;
    std::string::size_type n = std::min( s.size(), std::prev( it )->first.size() );
    auto pos = std::mismatch( s.begin(), std::next( s.begin(), n ),
                              std::prev( it )->first.begin() );
    prev = std::distance( s.begin(), pos.first );
}       
if ( it != test.end() )
{
    std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
    std::string::size_type n = std::min( s.size(), std::prev( it )->first.size() );
    auto pos = std::mismatch( s.begin(), std::next( s.begin(), n ),
                              it->first.begin() );
    prev = std::distance( s.begin(), pos.first );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but when i compile, i get below error:

Comment: sample.cpp(165): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
sample.cpp(165): error C2227: left of '->first' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
sample.cpp(165): error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
sample.cpp(166): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>sample.cpp(166): error C2227: left of '->first' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
sample.cpp(166): error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union
std::mismatch(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InTy (&)[_InSize])' : expects 3 arguments - 4 provided

Comment: @S Sriniamul It seems that you have an old llibrary that does not support  algorithm std::mismatch with four parameters. Wait a minute I will show how to use the old algorithm.